# Exception caught by widgets library in bottom navigation bar

Tags: flutter, dart

> Hi, anyone know what the problem is? I'm trying to add a bottom navigation bar, but the following message is showing i tried to add bottom navigation bar and this is the code i made.

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Builder(builder: (context) {
          return Scaffold(
            bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
              type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
              selectedFontSize: 12,
              unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey,
              items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.home),
                  label: 'Beranda',
                ),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.school),
                  label: 'Akademik',
                ),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.credit_card),
                  label: 'Pembayaran',
                ),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.person),
                  label: 'Profile',
                ),
              ],
              currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
              selectedItemColor: primaryColor,
              onTap: (index) {
                setState(
                  () {
                    _selectedIndex = index;
                  },
                );
              },
            ),
            body: Column(
              children: [
                _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
                body(),
              ],
            ),
          );
        }),
      ),
    );
  }
```

> but when I try to run it the following error occurs, and I feel a little confused, I've tried to find some references but still can't find a solution that fits my case

```
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
lib\main.dart:1
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Connecting to VM Service at ws://127.0.0.1:62216/ZIcDnqzIkLk=/ws
E/SurfaceSyncer( 7593): Failed to find sync for id=0
W/Parcel  ( 7593): Expecting binder but got null!
D/EGL_emulation( 7593): app_time_stats: avg=7.90ms min=2.99ms max=180.93ms count=62
D/EGL_emulation( 7593): app_time_stats: avg=15.06ms min=3.37ms max=21.43ms count=60

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following StackOverflowError was thrown building Builder:
Stack Overflow

The relevant error-causing widget was
Builder
lib\…\homepage\home_page.dart:31
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
```

> this my home_page.dart

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

int _selectedIndex = 0;
final List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
  const HomePage(),
  const AcademicPage(),
  const CreditPage(),
  const ProfilePage(),
];

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Scaffold(
          bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
            type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
            selectedFontSize: 12,
            unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey,
            items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.home),
                label: 'Beranda',
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.school),
                label: 'Akademik',
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.credit_card),
                label: 'Pembayaran',
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.person),
                label: 'Profile',
              ),
            ],
            currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
            selectedItemColor: primaryColor,
            onTap: (index) {
              setState(
                () {
                  _selectedIndex = index;
                },
              );
            },
          ),
          body: Column(
            children: [
              _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
              body(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }


  Widget body() {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        const SizedBox(
          height: 30,
        ),
        Container(
          child: FutureBuilder<UserBiodata>(
            future: AuthProvider().getDataMahasiswa(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                // return Text(snapshot.data!.status);
                return Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          '${snapshot.data!.data.name}',
                          style: bold4,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          '${snapshot.data!.data.prodi}',
                          style: bold6,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          'Semester ${snapshot.data!.data.smt}',
                          style: regular6,
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                    Image.asset(
                      'assets/images/user.png',
                      width: 60,
                    ),
                  ],
                );
              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Text('${snapshot.error}');
              }
              return const CircularProgressIndicator();
            },
          ),
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 30,
        ),
        Image.asset(
          'assets/images/statis.png',
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 30,
        ),
        Text(
          'Akses Cepat',
          style: bold4,
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 18,
        ),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
          children: [
            Container(
              height: 90,
              width: 90,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                  Radius.circular(20),
                ),
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.2),
                    spreadRadius: 1,
                    blurRadius: 9,
                    offset: const Offset(1, 2), // changes position of shadow
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                  Image.asset(
                    'assets/images/icon_jadwal.png',
                    height: 40,
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 12,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    'Jadwal Kuliah',
                    style: regular7,
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              height: 90,
              width: 90,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                  Radius.circular(20),
                ),
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.2),
                    spreadRadius: 1,
                    blurRadius: 9,
                    offset: const Offset(1, 2), // changes position of shadow
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                  Image.asset(
                    'assets/images/icon_jadwal.png',
                    height: 40,
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 12,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    'Jadwal Kuliah',
                    style: regular7,
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              height: 90,
              width: 90,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                  Radius.circular(20),
                ),
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.2),
                    spreadRadius: 1,
                    blurRadius: 9,
                    offset: const Offset(1, 2), // changes position of shadow
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                  Image.asset(
                    'assets/images/icon_jadwal.png',
                    height: 40,
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 12,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    'Jadwal Kuliah',
                    style: regular7,
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 18,
        ),
        Text(
          'Dosen',
          style: bold4,
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 18,
        ),
        Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
              Radius.circular(8),
            ),
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.2),
                spreadRadius: 1,
                blurRadius: 9,
                offset: const Offset(1, 2), // changes position of shadow
              ),
            ],
          ),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(14),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      'Muhamad Fahmi Nugraha M.Kom',
                      style: bold6,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'kaprodi Fakultas Komputer',
                      style: bold7,
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 12,
                    ),
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          width: 94,
                          height: 32,
                          child: TextButton(
                            onPressed: () => showDialog(
                              context: context,
                              builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                                  _signOutDialog(context),
                            ),
                            style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                              backgroundColor: primaryColor,
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                              ),
                            ),
                            child: Text(
                              "WhatsApp",
                              style: boldButton1,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(
                          width: 8,
                        ),
                        Container(
                          width: 94,
                          height: 32,
                          child: TextButton(
                            onPressed: (() {
                              var result = Navigator.pushNamed(
                                context,
                                AppRoute.biodataeRoute,
                              );
                            }),
                            style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                              backgroundColor: button,
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                              ),
                            ),
                            child: Text(
                              "Detail",
                              style: boldButton2,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                Image.asset(
                  'assets/images/user.png',
                  width: 50,
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 18,
        ),
        Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
              Radius.circular(8),
            ),
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.2),
                spreadRadius: 1,
                blurRadius: 9,
                offset: const Offset(1, 2), // changes position of shadow
              ),
            ],
          ),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(14),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      'Muhamad Fahmi Nugraha M.Kom',
                      style: bold6,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'kaprodi Fakultas Komputer',
                      style: bold7,
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 12,
                    ),
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          width: 94,
                          height: 32,
                          child: TextButton(
                            onPressed: () {},
                            style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                              backgroundColor: primaryColor,
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                              ),
                            ),
                            child: Text(
                              "WhatsApp",
                              style: boldButton1,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(
                          width: 8,
                        ),
                        Container(
                          width: 94,
                          height: 32,
                          child: TextButton(
                            onPressed: () {},
                            style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                              backgroundColor: button,
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                              ),
                            ),
                            child: Text(
                              "Detail",
                              style: boldButton2,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                Image.asset(
                  'assets/images/user.png',
                  width: 50,
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

Widget _signOutDialog(BuildContext context) {
  return AlertDialog(
    title: Column(
      children: [
        Image.asset(
          'assets/images/ic_lgt.png',
        )
      ],
    ),
    content: const Text('Apakah kamu yakin ingin logout?'),
    actions: <Widget>[
      TextButton(
        onPressed: () => AuthProvider().signOut(context),
        child: const Text('Ya'),
      ),
      TextButton(
        onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
        child: const Text(
          'TIDAK',
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  );
}
```

Comment: please provide more code. this may cause when you called any funtion on initState or anywhere

Answer (score 2):

replace your code with this.

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child:Scaffold(
            bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
              type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
              selectedFontSize: 12,
              unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey,
              items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.home),
                  label: 'Beranda',
                ),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.school),
                  label: 'Akademik',
                ),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.credit_card),
                  label: 'Pembayaran',
                ),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.person),
                  label: 'Profile',
                ),
              ],
              currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
              selectedItemColor: primaryColor,
              onTap: (index) {
                setState(
                  () {
                    _selectedIndex = index;
                  },
                );
              },
            ),
            body: Column(
              children: [
                _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
                body(),
              ],
            ),
          ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: the error still occurs as above